# Alter RewriteRule to change parameter results

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2

Here is my Apache 2 Directory configuration:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/website/>
        Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?operator=$1&url=$2 [L,QSA]
        RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?operator=$1 [L,QSA]
</Directory>
```

If I enter http://example.com/website/a/b then I see: `?operator=a&url=b`. This is fine and is what I expect.
If I enter http://example.com/website/a/ then I see: `?operator=a&url=`. This is also fine and expected.

My problem is the result of http://example.com/website/. What I see is `?operator=index.php&url=`.
I expected to see both parameters empty, but operator is populated with 'index.php'.

How can I alter my 'RewriteRule's so that the parameters are both empty when then there are no directories trailing after website as shown in my example?

Answer (score 0):

It is because rewrite rule is running twice because `RewriteCond` is applied to next immediate `RewriteRule`.

Change your rules to:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/website/>
        Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?operator=$1&url=$2 [L,QSA]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?operator=$1 [L,QSA]
</Directory>
```